# onClick communication between content and background scripts not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am making an application that highlights key words in the current page after the user clicks my icon. I am trying to communicate between my content scripts and background script. However,my code is not working. Does anyone know how it should be written?

Here is my content script:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(active,sender,sendResponse){
if(active.length>0){
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//rest of word highlighting code
}
})
```

here is my background.js :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

  chrome.extension.sendRequest(active);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do **not** use the deprecated `chrome.extension.sendRequest` and matching events. They are old, broken and not supported, which is quite clearly said in the documentation - which shows that you did not go and read it.

   The correct ones to use are `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `.onMessage`, but otherwise the signature is the same.
2. Well.. Why did you expect that to work? (unless you're not really showing us all relevant code, which is.. not helpful)

   ```
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

     // There is no "active" in the code anywhere to this point.
     //   It is treated like a variable name, one that was not yet used,
     //   so its contents are "undefined", and that's what you're sending.
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage(active);
     // Equivalent code: chrome.runtime.sendMessage(undefined);

   });
   ```

   And on the receiving side:

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(active,sender,sendResponse){
     // So, here "active" is undefined. It does not have a length
     //   parameter, and as such causes a fatal exception
     //   "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
     //   that you might have seen in the console of the page
     if(active.length>0){
       /* something */ 
     }
   })
   ```

Whatever you send is usually, but not always, an object (well, it must be JSON-serializable). If you just want to trigger something and not pass any data, there are 2 often-used conventions, either is fine:

1. Pass command as a value.

   ```
   // Sender
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "active"});
   // Receiver
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
     if(message.command == "active"){
       /* something */ 
     }

     // or, useful if you have many different commands:

     switch(message.command){
       case "active":
         /* something */
         break;
     }
   });
   ```
2. Set a boolean in the message:

   ```
   // Sender
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({active: true});
   // Receiver
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
     if(message.active){
       /* something */ 
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: this seems like the answer. However when I run it I get a error that "Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined"